# Get value from x-editable select to another input with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I have, x-editable plugin which I'm using for select of privacy settings. Now my idea and need is to get selected value from menu in another independent text input. I've written a code but id does not work and I don't know why.... Am I missing something or what?

Situation: http://jsfiddle.net/neAWw/

html:

```
    <a href="#" id="privacy" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-value="1" data-original-title="Select visibility">public</a>

    <input id="privacy_result" class="privacy_result" value="1"/>

</div>
```

script:

```
 $('#privacy').editable({
    showbuttons: false,
    unsavedclass: null,
    type: 'select',
    inputclass: 'input-medium privacy-select',
    source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'public'},
        {value: 2, text: 'approved contacts only'},
        {value: 3, text: 'matching contacts'},
        {value: 4, text: 'invisible'}
    ],

});

$(function(){
        $('.privacy-select').on('change keyup blur', function(){
            $('.privacy_result').val($('.privacy-select').val());
        }).blur();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know the plugin but try something like this:
(see HTML Markup in fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/neAWw/2/

```
  $(function(){
            $('.parentToDelegate').on('change keyup blur', ".privacy-select", function(){
                $('.privacy_result').val($('.privacy-select').val());
            }).blur();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also simply add the following line to your editable function as an extra attribute:

```
 success:function(){
            $('.privacy_result').val($('.privacy-select').val());
    }
```

Here you are an example: http://jsfiddle.net/neAWw/2/embedded/result/